# How can I find out the size of a java.util.List if the actual size is greater than the Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: java, list, size

As I understood `java.util.List` does not have size restrictions. As I understand, the size() method:

> Returns the number of elements in this list. If this list contains
>   more than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements, returns Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Therefore I have following question:

If my `List` has a size that is larger than the `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, is there a way to determine the exact size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to count them yourself, using a bigger data type.

```
long realSize;

if (myList.size() < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    realSize = myList.size();
} else {
    realSize = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    ListIterator<Foo> iter = myList.listIterator(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      realSize++;
      iter.next();
    }
 }
```

Comment: it would works if **(realSize-Integer.MAX_VALUE) < Integer.MAX_VALUE**

Comment: @gstackoverflow What ? This counts the number of elements if .size() says it's Integer.MAX_VALUE (meaning it could actually be more elements than Integer.MAX_VALUE). We use a listIterator to start iterating at Integer.MAX_VALUE instead of starting at 0.

Comment: Sorry it would works only if your natural size < Long.MAX_VALUE

Comment: While this technically works, you would pretty much never actually do this. The list would offer some other API to get the size, and you'd use that.

Comment: @gstackoverflow Ofcourse. For the forseable future you cannot get a computer with enough memory to store Long.MAX_VALUE of anything though.

Comment: @user2357112 The standard java.util.LinkedList does not offer such an API, though it isn't limited at Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: @nos: Yes it is. The implementation tracks size with an `int` variable that's unconditionally incremented when elements are added; thus, it breaks down if the size overflows. At the very least, it breaks the contract of the `size` method; I haven't checked the rest of it.

Comment: Looked through the source code some more. There are a ton of bounds checks all over the place that start throwing exceptions when the size overflows. Even `iterator()` has a range check in it, so you can't iterate over the list to count the elements.

Comment: @user2357112 Hmm...research LinkedList#add method.... **addBefore(element, (index==size ? header : entry(index)));** =>  **Entry<E> newEntry = new Entry<E>(e, entry, entry.previous);
 newEntry.previous.next = newEntry;
 newEntry.next.previous = newEntry;
 size++;
 modCount++;
 return newEntry;     ** I don't see check about overflowing int field size

Comment: @gstackoverflow: `add(Object)` itself doesn't bounds check. It'll happily overflow `size` and keep adding elements. When you try to call `get`, `iterator`, or any of the other methods that do bounds checks after `size` overflows, they'll fail `index < size` and throw an error.

Comment: @gstackoverflow: After what? Even if `size` overflows all the way back up to positives, the iterator relies on a `nextIndex` variable to determine whether it's reached the end of the list, so it won't iterate over the whole thing. The code is just so heavily reliant on the `size >= 0` invariant, everything comes crashing down if that invariant breaks.

Comment: @user2357112 I can use List without using iterator

Comment: @gstackoverflow: How are you going to access the items? `get`? That breaks. `poll`? That doesn't seem to break, but then you're stuck with effectively just a deque, and you're tiptoeing around the holes in an implementation that was never designed to handle such huge sizes. Who knows whether the next version of the JDK will break your code?

Comment: @user2357112 YES. thus I think that such product as java should't have these holes!!!

Comment: @nos if **myList** is **LinkedList** - your code will not work

Answer (score 0):

If a list supports sizes that huge, it will almost certainly support some sort of alternate `size` method you can use to get the size as a long. For example, the first such implementation I found, [HugeCollections](https://code.google.com/p/vanilla-java/wiki/HugeCollections), has a `longSize` method. The overhead of trying to get the true size without such a method is simply absurd.

I don't think any standard library List implementation supports sizes that huge; ArrayList and LinkedList don't. If you ever need to deal with this kind of problem, the documentation for the giant list type you're using should tell you what to do.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the specific implementation of `List` you are using. For example `ArrayList` uses a java array internally, which has a max size of `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5`. Other implementations of `List` might have different max sizes.

Comment: **Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5** I saw this answer on SO -but I am sure that it is wrong